# How to retrieve a `MaterialColor` instead of `Color` from a `ThemeData` in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

What I'm trying to achieve is to use a color swatch for painting on canvas with dynamically calculated shade index to utilize different shades of a specific swatch from the currently applied theme.

```
    int colorIndex = 700;
    Paint paintFill = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
      ..strokeWidth = 6.0
      ..color = (Theme.of(_context).primaryColor as MaterialColor)[colorIndex];
    for (int i = currentHour12; i >= 0; i--) {
      angleInDegrees = 30 * i;
      angleInRadians = (angleInDegrees-90) * pi / 180.0;
      canvas.drawArc(
          Rect.fromCircle(center: centerCurrent, radius: radius),
          angleInRadians,
          -angleSweepInRadians,
          true,
          paintFill
      );
      if (i % 2 == 0) colorIndex -= 100;
      paintFill = Paint()
        ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
        ..strokeWidth = 6.0
        ..color = (Theme.of(_context).primaryColor as MaterialColor)[colorIndex];
    }
```

With the current code above it works but with an error which makes sense:

> type 'Color' is not a subtype of type 'MaterialColor' in type cast

In my theme `primaryColor` is set to `MaterialColor`:

```
final darkTheme = ThemeData(
  brightness: Brightness.dark,
  primaryColor: Colors.indigo,
  ...
)
```

But it's retrieved as a simple `Color` with code like this:

```
(Theme.of(_context).primaryColor as MaterialColor)[colorIndex]
```

I've also tried to retrieve a `primarySwatch` property of a `ThemeData`, but it seems to be private.

Is there any way to get the whole swatch from a `ThemeData`? Or somehow typecast the `Color` back to `MaterialColor`?

Answer (score 2):

So I've ended up writing a helper function:

```
MaterialColor getMaterialColor(Color color) => Colors.primaries
  .firstWhere((element) => element.value == color.value);
```

which is called as following:

```
int colorIndex = 700;
MaterialColor primarySwatch = getMaterialColor(Theme.of(_context).primaryColor);
Paint paintFill = Paint()
  ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
  ..strokeWidth = 6.0
  ..color = primarySwatch[colorIndex];
```